# How do you rename an Entity Framework database after it has been created?

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

I am using EF 6 code first. As part of the code-based migration, I would like to rename the existing database after applying all the pending migrations. Can this be done?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How you supposed to tell migrations the database's name? Do you have a class that holds the database's name?

Comment: The original database name is set in the connection string. Migrate data then rename database.

code snippet:
var configuration = new Migrations.Configuration();
configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
dbMigrator.Update();
//rename database here

Comment: I believe that it is not the purpose of data migrations. However, I'm not sure. Be aware that if you change database's name in migrations, you have to change the web.config too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would be (easily?) possible (without causing errors)

If you rename the database during the migration it wont be able to write the migration out to the migrationhistory table as the connection string will still be pointing to the old database.

Perhaps a better option would be to build something into the system to rename the database and adjust the required configuration outside of EF entirely.